# Ubuntu 12.04 hangs on reboot ("All processes ended within 1 seconds"); how to debug?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, freeze, reboot

I read through a lot of ubuntuforums threads and tried out various things. Still freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit, 3.2.0-38) hangs on reboot/shutdown after the line "All processes ended within 2 seconds".

What I tried so far without success

- remove plymouth (replace by a dummy package)
- kill almost all processes / unload almost all modules / unmount all devices manually before boot
- uninstall network manager, modem manager, bluetoothd, ureadahead etc.
- tried several boot parameters (acpi=*, reboot=* etc.)
- disabled ipv6
- ifdown'ing the ethernet devices

Killing everything with `Alt+SysRq+e` and `Alt+SysRq+i` doesn't help either.

The logs don't show anything unusual.

Rebooting with `Alt+SysRq+b` or `reboot -f` does work, but it's not how I'd like it to.

I'm out of ideas of where to look and how to debug. Please help with some advice!

Answer (score 1):

try change in /etc/default/grub following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=p"
```

or

```
reboot=b
```

or something else according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/boot-options.txt

then

```
sudo update-grub
```